# Can a front controller or any other controller can be called an example of mediator pattern?

Tags: design-patterns

I see a similarity between the intent of mediator and front controller. Both basically controls/mediate to promote loose coupling.

I know mediator is not a GOF pattern. So thinking from that perspective can a controller/front controller be called an example/subset of mediator pattern.

If not can somebody give me a concrete example from a real syste, or from core java or any framework where it can be called a front controller but not mediator and vice versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Mediator is a dependency you inject in classes which they will use to communicate. A Mediator is not created nor it creates the classes it helps. Furthermore, both the mediator and the concrete classes know about each other. The Mediator controls a many-to-many network of communication.

```
class MainApp
{
  static void Main()
  {
    var m = new ConcreteMediator();

    var c1 = new ConcreteColleague1(m);
    var c2 = new ConcreteColleague2(m);

    m.Colleague1 = c1;
    m.Colleague2 = c2;

    c1.Send("How are you?");
    c2.Send("Fine, thanks");

    // Wait for user 
    Console.Read();
  }
}
```

<sup>[source](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/mediator/c-sharp-dot-net)</sup>

A Front Controller is an object that sits on top of your business model and handles incoming web requests. In ASP.NET an example would be an HTTPHandler (an object which controls all incoming requests and dispatches them). A Front Controller separates the "web server" logic from the "handle a specific request" logic, and as such it knows how to create the correct objects for it. Also, it is used to perform AOP-style behavior injection in requests. <sup>[source 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern), [source 2](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/frontController.html)</sup>

```
public class FrontController
{
   public Response HandleRequest(Request request)
   {
       try
       {
         EnsureRequestIsValid(Request request);
         var controller = FindController(request);
         return controller.HandleRequest(request);
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
         return new ErrorResponse(ex); // Exceptions become error pages!
       }
   }

   private MVCController FindController(Request request)
   {
      // some logic here to choose and create the right MVC controller...
      // in reality typically the current application introspects here to find
      // the right controller and method, but you get my point...

      if (Request.Path.StartsWith("/foo/"))
      {
         return new FooController();
      }
   }

   private void EnsureRequestIsValid(Request request)
   {
      // the logic here is always executed, it should throw on error
   }
}
```

As you can see, they are very different beasts: the mediator promotes communication from classes to classes, the front controller centralizes the communication from a third party and dispatches it to a single appropriate class. Furthermore a mediator must be agnostic of the classes being created -- in fact, it is dependency injected just for this purpose -- whereas a front controller must know which class to create depending on context -- it can use a factory for that, but it is still responsible for invoking the "create" method.